# JQGrid multi-value column concatenating selector

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, selector, concatenation, xmlreader

This is my problem:

I have an XMLReader like this:

```
root: "response>claims",
row: "claim",
repeatitems: false,
id: "claimId"
```

and an XML data structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<response>
    <claims>
        <claim>
            <actions />
            <adjusters />
            <claimId>254</claimId>
            <parties />
            <claimSubmitInd>N</claimSubmitInd>
            <claimTypeCd>AUTO</claimTypeCd>
            <units>
                <unit>
                    <claimId>254</claimId>
                    <insertId>sselvaraj</insertId>
                    <insertTmstmp>2012-10-24 18:07:47.167</insertTmstmp>
                    <roleCategory>veh_1st</roleCategory>
                    <sourceSystemCd>FNOL</sourceSystemCd>
                    <unitCategory>veh</unitCategory>
                    <coverages />
                    <damages />
                    <unitDataType>veh</unitDataType>
                    <unitId>1</unitId>
                    <unitSubType>sch</unitSubType>
                    <unitType>veh</unitType>
                    <updateId>sselvaraj</updateId>
                    <updateTmstmp>2012-10-24 18:07:47.167</updateTmstmp>
                </unit>
                <unit>
                    <claimId>254</claimId>
                    <insertId>sselvaraj</insertId>
                    <insertTmstmp>2012-10-24 18:14:07.437</insertTmstmp>
                    <roleCategory>veh_1st</roleCategory>
                    <sourceSystemCd>FNOL</sourceSystemCd>
                    <unitCategory>veh</unitCategory>
                    <coverages />
                    <damages />
                    <unitDataType>veh</unitDataType>
                    <unitId>2</unitId>
                    <unitSubType>sch</unitSubType>
                    <unitType>veh</unitType>
                    <updateId>sselvaraj</updateId>
                    <updateTmstmp>2012-10-24 18:14:07.437</updateTmstmp>
                </unit>
                <unit>
                    <claimId>254</claimId>
                    <insertId>sselvaraj</insertId>
                    <insertTmstmp>2012-10-24 18:17:47.597</insertTmstmp>
                    <roleCategory>veh_1st</roleCategory>
                    <sourceSystemCd>FNOL</sourceSystemCd>
                    <unitCategory>veh</unitCategory>
                    <coverages />
                    <damages />
                    <unitDataType>veh</unitDataType>
                    <unitId>3</unitId>
                    <unitSubType>sch</unitSubType>
                    <unitType>veh</unitType>
                    <updateId>sselvaraj</updateId>
                    <updateTmstmp>2012-10-24 18:17:47.597</updateTmstmp>
                </unit>
            </units>
            <clmAdjUserId>0</clmAdjUserId>
            <companyCd>06</companyCd>
            <injuryInd>N</injuryInd>
            <insInjAsPasInd>N</insInjAsPasInd>
            <insInjAsPedInd>N</insInjAsPedInd>
            <keyedDt>2012-10-24</keyedDt>
            <lossTmUnkInd>N</lossTmUnkInd>
            <othPropDmgInd>N</othPropDmgInd>
            <polFireAtSceneInd>N</polFireAtSceneInd>
            <rptOnlyInd>N</rptOnlyInd>
            <towClaimInd>N</towClaimInd>
            <witnessInd>N</witnessInd>
        </claim>
    </claims>
    <request>
        <expand>claim,units</expand>
        <filter>claimId eq 254</filter>
        <format>xml</format>
        <orderBy>claimId desc</orderBy>
        <orderByCol>claimId</orderByCol>
        <orderByDir>desc</orderByDir>
        <top>10</top>
    </request>
</response>
```

If my columns are defined like this:

```
    colModel: [
        { 
            name:  "claimId", 
            index:  "claimId", 
            width: 20, 
            xmlmap: ">claimId", 
            align: "right",
            sorttype: 'int',                
            hidden: false,
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: soptnums,
                attr: {style: "text-align: right;"}
            }                
        }
        ,{ 
            name:  "unitId", 
            index:  "unitId", 
            width: 20, 
            xmlmap: "units>unit>unitId", 
            align: "center",
            sorttype: 'int',                
            hidden: false,
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: soptnums,
                attr: {style: "text-align: center;"}
            }                
        }
```

then I see the claim id node value just fine and a concatenation of all corresponding matches for unitId node values in the units collection.

So, I see something like

```
Claim Id           Unit Id

254                123
```

My question is this: how do I write the selector for the UnitId xmlmap so that the concatenation produces a string like this "1|2|3" or "1 separator 2 separator 3"?
I tried several things and I saw, for example, that xmlmap: "units>unit>unitId:first" only shows the 1 (first matched node).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use in such cases `xmlmap` defined as function. For example in your case you can use

```
xmlmap: function (obj) {
    return $(">units>unit>unitId", obj).map(function() {
               return $(this).text();
           }).get().join("|");
}
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Concatenating.htm):

[image]

Comment: Oleg, buddy, I am no Tina Turner but, when it comes about JQGrid, "you are simply the best"!